# Active: failed (Result: signal) service odoo12 failed Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, odoo

I have a problem with my Odoo when the odoo service is run and then accessed via the website, the service status on Ubuntu says active failed with a signal result.

[image: image show error failed]

Comment: this is ubuntu 18.04 server system

Comment: ok i already change it